# Default select option is not being updated in DOM, even though the v-model attribute is updating

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue.js

I have a component that builds a select/dropdown menu.

There is an API call that results in both `collection` and `selectedOption` getting updated and successfully building the dropdown.

```
<!-- src/components/systems/SystemEdit.vue -->    
<custom-dropdown v-model="system.sensor_type" id="sensor_type" name="sensor_type" :collection="sensorTypeDropdown.collection" :firstOption="sensorTypeDropdown.firstOption" :selectedOption="sensorTypeDropdown.selected"></custom-dropdown>


<!-- src/components/CustomDropdown.vue -->
<template>
  <select v-model="selection" required="">
    <option v-show="firstOption" value="null">{{firstOption}}</option>
    <option v-for="item in collection" :value="item[1]">{{ item[0] }}</option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['value', 'firstOption', 'collection', 'selectedOption'],
    name: 'customDropdown',
    data () {
      return {
        selection: null
      }
    },
    watch: {
      selection: function(sel) {
        this.selection = sel
        this.$emit('input',sel)
      }
    },
    updated: function() {
      if(this.selectedOption) {
        this.selection = this.selectedOption
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

The dropdown output looks like this:

```
<select required="required" id="sensor_type" name="sensor_type">
    <option value="null">Select sensor type...</option>
    <option value="sensor1">sensor1</option>
    <option value="sensor2">sensor2</option>
    <option value="sensor3">sensor3</option>
</select>
```

If I set the `selection: "sensor1"` data attribute, then `sensor1` is selected, as expected.

Instead, if I update `this.selection = this.selectedOption` or `this.selection = "sensor1"`, then it does *not* become the selected option… even though `console.log(this.selection)` confirms the change. I have tried setting it in the `created` hook and elsewhere. If I save a change, the dropdown default successfully sets on the hot reload. But that first load where it initializes will not work.

How can I get `this.selection = this.selectedOption` to properly reflect in the DOM to show that option as selected?

I'm using Vue 2.1.10

**Edit 1:**

Still no luck, now with this approach:

```
data () {
  return {
    selection: this.setSelected()
  }
},
methods: {
  setSelected: function() {
    var sel = null
    if(this.selectedOption) {
      sel = this.selectedOption
    }
    console.log(sel)
    return sel
  }
}
```

Even though `sel` outputs "sensor1" and the Vue inspector confirms `selection:"sensor1"`

**Edit 2:**

I've narrowed down the problem but cannot yet find a solution.

```
methods: {
  setSelected: function() {
    var sel = null
    if(this.selectedOption) {
      sel = this.selectedOption
    }
    return sel
  }
}
```

It fails on `return sel`.

`sel` is not being treated as a string; I suspect this is a Vue bug.

Works:

```
return 'sensor1'
```

Fails:

```
return sel
```

I have tried all these workarounds (none of them work):

```
sel = String(this.selectedOption)
sel = (this.selectedOption).toString()
sel = new String(this.selectedOption)
sel = this.selectedOption+''
sel = 'sensor1'
```

The only way this will "work" is if I use the string literal, which is useless to me.

I am stumped.

**SOLVED**

In order for this to work, the `selectedOption` prop that I am passing to the component must be rendered *somewhere* in the component's template, even if you have no use for it in the template.

Fails:

```
<select v-model="selection" required="">
```

Works:

```
<select v-model="selection" required="" :data-selected="selectedOption">
```

That data attribute can be `:data-whatever`… as long as it is rendered somewhere in the template.

This works, too:

```
<option v-show="!selectedOption" value="null">{{selectedOption}}</option>
```

or

```
<div :id="selectedOption"></div>
```

I hope this helps someone. I'm going to let Evan You know about it, as it seems to be something that should be fixed or at least noted in the official documentation.

**Summary:**

Props used in a component's script block must also be rendered somewhere in the component's template, otherwise some unexpected behaviour may occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prop I am using in the script block, `selectedOption`, needs to be rendered in the template even though it's not being used there.

So this:

```
<select v-model="selection" required="">
```

becomes:

```
<select v-model="selection" required="" :data-selected="selectedOption">
```

Now the `selected` item successfully updates in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

VueJS has a specific configuration for [v-model on custom components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events).  In particular the component should have a `value` prop, which will pick up the `v-model` from the parent.  You then `this.$emit('input', newVal)` on change like you have configured.

I'm not sure exactly where the breakdown is with your component but [here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/nonadmin/rf01281L/).  You may have just over complicated changing the selected data.  If configured correctly you can just emit the change and let the parent handle actually updating what is assigned to `v-model`.  In the example I included some buttons to change the selected var from both the parent and component to illustrate changing the var (parent) or emitting a change (component).

Comment: As you can see in my code sample, I am already using `$emit` and the `value` prop. The complication comes when the selected value needs to be set via dynamic data in the code… rather than via the user interacting with the dropdown.

Comment: Within the component it looks like you're using `v-model`, and then the `updated` life cycle hook to emit changes, which I don't think is optimal in this case.

Comment: In terms of setting the value, see what the button click functions are doing in the jsfiddle I posted.

Comment: I get what you mean now. Thanks for the code sample. So I've refactored my code a bit, to use `emit` more fully… but my original issue and solution remain unchanged: I still must render `selectedOption` in the template in order to make use of that prop in the script block.

Comment: I'm not sure of the reasoning with `selectedOption`.  Why not just manipulate the actual value of `v-model` with either emits or by directly setting it in the parent?

Comment: Both of those approaches failed me in this case. I don't know if it's because it's a single-file component or because the props data is sourced from an API call or what. The value of `v-model` will vary, depending on use. So the component has its own `v-model` for its inner workings and its parent associates it with the appropriate `v-model`.